# Browser plugin to analyze Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, profiling, browser-extension

Does anyone know of a browser plugin (Chrome, Safari or Firefox) that would give me a detailed look into Javascript function execution time and resources? I'm aware of Firefox/Firebug's `console.profile()` but I'm looking for something that can analyze all functions from within the browser vs having to manually enter this code into my scripts. If there is no browser plugin for this, maybe a standalone one similar to dynaTrace but for Mac.

Comment: I'm confused, what do you want in addition to what every browser debugger already does? FF/WK/IE9+ all have javascript profilers built in.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge in FF (and probably other browsers that i havent tested) i need to add a console.profile('Profile start') and console.profileEnd() in order to get what I'm looking for.  The problem here is say i have 5k+ lines of javascript over multiple files and I dont know where the bottleneck is.  I dont want to have to implement the console.profile() on every function.  I would like to be able to see a list of all the functions being executed, their execution time, and possibly even the amount of memory being used.

Comment: In chrome for example, F12, profiles tab, black cirlce starts profiling.

Answer (score 1):

This exists in all current browsers already.

In Firebug, select Profile under the console tab.

In any WebKit flavour or IE9, there is a Profiles tab.

Don't know personally about Opera.